# Storyboard - static cell in Detail view - managing buttons dynamically

Tags: objective-c

I've recently found a way to solve displaying a button when data exists and not when no data is in a cell.   Specifically using Storyboards in a detail view (static cell). This button is a necessity on the Storyboard due to some seque wiring I've hooked up.

I placed a custom button with no background image on it, and set a tag value of the tableviewcell to 1.

Then in my implementation file I've overridden the cellForRowAtIndexPath.
My question is, while this works fine, is it performance intensive?  I have only 5 cells in this MOC.  Here's my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // need to capture the section and the cell to modify....

    if (cell.tag == 1){

        if (self.map){

            self.mapButton.enabled = YES;

            self.mapLabel.text = @"Click Map for Pic Location...";

            UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyMap.png"];
            [self.mapButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];


        } else{
            self.mapLabel.text = @"No Location found for Pic";
            self.mapButton.enabled = NO;
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Why would this be "performance intensive"? Are you seeing poor scrolling or other performance issues on the device?

Comment: Since I only have a few cell on the detail view maybe it's not.  I'll step thru an examine further.  It seemed a bit "chatty" on first glance.   Perhaps I thought it was sort of too good to be true that I found this way of managing this solution.